# Load Remote File with TWIG

Tags: php, twig, symfony-2.3

Using Twig in Symfony 2.3 I need to be able to select remote assets inside a twig template.

So I have a twig template with a body block like this:

```
{% block body %}
    {% include 'http://asset.remotelocation.co.uk/template.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

and as you can see its trying to include a remote twig template.  Is this possible as symfony just errors saying it cant find the template?

The twig template location is correct in my code as I can browse to the template url in my browser.

Any help is much appeciated. =)

P.S the remote location is just one of our other webserver where we hold shared assets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a function that will download this file for you, and make it available for twig.

The idea :

- You create a directory `app/Resources/views/temp`, so a twig files can be accessed at `:temp:file.html.twig`
- In your twig file, you'll use a `remote_file()` function to wrap the first `include`'s argument
- Your files will be downloaded by your function inside `temp` directory with a *random* name
- your function will return a twig path to access the file locally (the `:temp:file.html.twig`)
- don't forget to automate something to clear too old temp files! (a cron?)

## The directory

Create a temp directory so that your symfony directory tree looks like this:

[image]

## The extension

Inside your bundle, create a `Twig\Extension` directory. There, create a `RemoteFileExtension.php` file with the following code. Note: don't forget to replace my namespaces by yours.

```
<?php

namespace Fuz\TestBundle\Twig\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class RemoteFileExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    private $kernel;

    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
                'remote_file' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'remote_file'),
        );
    }

    public function remote_file($url)
    {
        $contents = file_get_contents($url);
        $file = $this->kernel->getRootDir() . "/Resources/views/temp/" . sha1($contents) . '.html.twig';
        if (!is_file($file))
        {
            file_put_contents($file, $contents);
        }
        return ':temp:' . basename($file);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'remote_file';
    }

}
```

Inside your `services.yml` configuration file, add the following:

below `parameters`:

```
fuz_tools.twig.remote_file_extension.class: Fuz\TestBundle\Twig\Extension\RemoteFileExtension
```

below `services`:

```
fuz_tools.twig.remote_file_extension:
    class: '%fuz_tools.twig.remote_file_extension.class%'
    arguments: ['@kernel']
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

## Test it!

I created an existing `http://localhost:8888/test.html.twig`. It only contains:

```
Hello, {{ name }}!
```

Inside my application, I put the following line :

```
{% include remote_file('http://localhost:8888/test.html.twig') with {'name': 'Alain'} %}
```

When I run my code, I get :

[image]

### Some more notes

You should consider that a twig file takes part of your application. A twig file is not an asset, as it needs to be intepreted by Symfony2, with some logic, with some optimizations and so on. What you're doing actually is comparable to a remote include of a PHP file before executing it, strange architecture I think.

Anyway, your question was interesting, good luck for your implementation.

Comment: wow Alain top marks for such a complete answer.  Im off to test this out and shall be back with my outcomes soon.  Thank you =)