# Including external html files in twig template

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I want to include an external html page in my twig template when I do it  an exception is fired saying that

```
Unable to find template "http://*********.com/page.html in UserBundle:sec:app.html.twig at line 6.


500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Loader
2 linked Exceptions:
InvalidArgumentException »
InvalidArgumentException »
```

I want to know if there is a way to do this

Comment: Post the part of the twig file that has the include so we can see what you did

Comment: Do you mean external as in, located on another server besides your own? I don't think that's possible with pure Twig, and even if it is possible, I wouldn't recommend doing it as it would be very slow.

Comment: well  the file i try to includ is localted in my server but outside the symfony project  it's another project made with angular so i want to redirect to this page without revealing it's path

Comment: You're question isn't descriptive enough. Add example code of what is causing the error, to help show people what the problem is coming from.

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030721/load-remote-file-with-twig