# How to include external html files in my twig template?

Tags: php, html, twig

I have extracted some html into a different repository for re-use, and have since been re-including it in various repos via `<? php include_once('path/to/code)`. However I have come up against a repo that uses `.html.twig` format.

As far as I have seen, I can't find a way of including this external file in my twig templage.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030721/load-remote-file-with-twig), but it appears to be a case of extreme overkill for a single file that will be used in one or two places.

Comment: you cant include php script in twig. you can only include or extend twig templates

Comment: @Zeljka I understand - Is there a simple way to include an external file, or am I flogging a dead horse?

Comment: Can you not convert it to a twig

Comment: That could be done, yes. But would that affect my other instances where I have imported via PHP into other HTML files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{% include 'your_page.html' %}`

I'm not sure this is working with a `.php` but you can try.

EDIT: I've been checking and indeed there is no way to include php into twig files to prevent design to include too much logic considering that twig brings already enough logic by itself.

So you can't include a php file like I were suggesting. The only way to do seems to convert your logic into an other `.html.twig` file that you will include or extends.

Comment: I think I confused you with my reference to PHP. I am including the my HTML in my regular files via PHP, but I know that PHP won't work in twig... I just want to know if it's possible to include my html by any means possible.

Comment: Well then the include I shown is what you need. What you need to know is just that depending of what types of module you are using you might need to set your html file in a specific location in that module. If you only look to include html into html twig, this is the way to go and it's not using php at all.

Comment: Cool beans! If I run into any issues, I'll tag you :-)